# How Call A Function From directives And fire a event in vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
Vue.directive('outside', {
    inserted: function (el) {

    },
    bind: function (el) {

    },
    update:function () {

    }
});
```

What is the best way to create directives And How to listen event who fire in directives

Comment: read this document but it is not Sufficient  document